# herokuapp subdomain not shown externally

Tags: database, heroku, subdomain

I have a `Facebook` app running on `Heroku`. The app has been created directly from the Facebook app creation wizard. The subdomain is like myapp.herokuapp.com. The problem is when I connect to an external `MySQL DB`, another subdomain (amazonaws) is presented to the MySQL server. This is the answer of MySQL server, which does not grant access because of unknown domain.

`Could not connect: Access denied for user 'mauro_wrdp2'@'ec2-23-22-65-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)`

What do I need to do to have herokuapp subdomain presented instead on Amazon AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect through your Herokuapp domain to your AWS instance - Postgres (not Mysql) runs separately to the applications which is why you have to connect directly to the AWS instance. I guess you would be free to CNAME your own domain to the AWS address but you run the risk of the DB being moved - Heroku would update the DATABASE_URL config variable on your behalf if this happened.

Comment: Ok, I thought heroku was a standalone solution. But actually it seems to offer only a platform, while all resources are taken externally (aws). I'm not using any db solution from heroku, and the app is a test app which for now dows nothing. I guess so the web server is taken from aws as well, and this is the domain is coming from. In mysql extern db i could enable *.amazons domain, but this seems to be a security threat. Thank you

Comment: ahhh, I'm with you now - you're talking about the source FQDN address that the Heroku application presents itself to your DB as to limit your mysql users to a domain which will indeed be an Amazon address but will change as your application is moved around the Heroku platform.